# Do you need a WakeLock for CPU intensive services?

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

It is not really clear to me from the documentation if a WakeLock should be used for my applications. In all cases these services are started with `startForeground()`:

1. Process audio and play on an `AudioTrack`. (CPU intensive).
2. Process audio and encode to a file. (CPU intensive).
3. Receive periodic location updates from Google Play Services (5-10 seconds apart, probably less CPU intensive).

I have tested the first two on my devices (stock Android 4.4 and 5.0) for > 15 minutes (likely longer than they will ever need to stay running), and the services continue running with the screen off and no WakeLock. The third one I have not yet tested. I realize devices can have different characteristics.

Should I be using a WakeLock for these services, or does the CPU activity keep the device from sleeping? They are not supposed to stop when the device isn't being used.

Comment: "I have tested the first two on my devices (stock Android 4.4 and 5.0)" Such test doesn't test anything except it has worked in this particular moment on this particular device. It may or may not work differently next time.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Yes, that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be using a WakeLock for these services

If you don't want the device to fall asleep, and nothing else is keeping the device awake, yes.

> does the CPU activity keep the device from sleeping?

No.

> the services continue running with the screen off and no WakeLock

Then either:

- your devices are plugged into power (and you have the associated developer setting to keep the CPU on while plugged in enabled), or
- something else is holding a `WakeLock`, or
- your hardware is specialized to not put the device in sleep mode, or
- you are misinterpreting your test results

Comment: Yup. Definitely take out a wake lock if you want the device to stay awake. Some devices are more aggressive than others, but many will certainly put your phone to sleep even if your app is doing something if they're not plugged into power (and most especially if they've been locked by the user.) I've tested this a lot, as I have an app (a talking exercise coach) which sporadically plays audio and is designed to work with the device locked.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess a followup question would be whether the execution state will be the same when the device wakes up again. For example, would the file saving service just resume where it left off when the device wakes up if no WakeLock was used?

Comment: @SteveM: While the CPU will resume right where it left off, I would not want to count on the status of any I/O (e.g., file, network). A network socket in particular has a good chance of being dropped (e.g., user was on WiFi, CPU went to sleep, user moved out of range of the access point). Disk I/O *may* be OK, but I haven't ever tried doing disk I/O and letting the device fall asleep, and I simply wouldn't trust it for my own work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks definitely will be adding the WakeLocks.

Comment: Do some devices not put the device into sleep at all? Because I've been testing on Android Studio emulators for days and sleep never interrupts anything I run in a service.

Comment: @FlorianWalther: Testing sleep behavior on an emulator is akin to measuring the blood pressure of a mannequin. The tests are unlikely to resemble real-world results. Run your tests on hardware.

Comment: I have started an IntentService on my Note 8, fed it with a huge amount of intents and let it run overnight (screen off, not charging). All intents executed one after another. I had to use a foreground service tho, since it's running Oreo. And the service just ran a for loop which freezes the thread.
I also tested doze on emulators with no effect. But the same doze deferred jobs, so it must be working.

Comment: @FlorianWalther: Perhaps something else on your device is holding a partial wakelock.

Comment: On my real device - maybe. On emulator I checked with dumpsys power. Let me ask you another way: Can you give me an example of a functionality that would stop working as soon as the device goes to sleep? Or should a service just stop completely? 
I've posted it as a new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317861/what-exact-functionality-stops-working-if-a-wake-lock-is-not-acquired-and-the-de