# What exact functionality stops working if a wake lock is not acquired and the device goes into sleep?

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

The last couple of days I've been trying to figure out which functionality in a service (background and foreground) stops working when the device falls into sleep without a wake lock. All the documentation only says that a wake lock "keeps the CPU from shutting down", but every single functionality I've tested kept working without a wake lock if I turned the screen off and unplugged the device. I've also checked via adb if another application is holding a wake lock, but the wake lock count is 0.

I've tested CPU heavy math calculations, network requests and playing music over MediaPlayer class. Everything kept working in a background service (below Oreo) without a wake lock (The network request worked on some emulators and on others not, but this was the same with and without a wake lock).

So my question is, what are examples for features that stop working on Android if the device falls into sleep?

Edit:
I want to make it clear that I am not talking about DOZE. I am talking about the device going into sleep and powering down the CPU, which is supposed to happen when screen is turned off and now wake lock is acquired.

Answer (score 2):

Doze mode does not mean the device is going permanently into the out of maintenance mode. It's more like quick naps between the window of actions. This is how it looks like

[image: Doze provides a recurring maintenance window for apps to use the network and handle pending activities.]

And these are the restrictions:

> Doze restrictions The following restrictions apply to your apps while
>
> - Network access is suspended.
> - The system ignores wake locks.
> - Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.
> - The system does not perform Wi-Fi scans.
> - The system does not allow sync adapters to run.
> - The system does not allow JobScheduler to run.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

To see if your app still works during the Doze mode you can force it. Don't use the emulator for that instead try it on a real device.

Use this to force doze mode

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

Unforce it

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle unforce
```

Reset it

```
adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

More to find here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze

Also keep in mind that the handling of doze and standby mode could be handled differently by the device manufacturer.

---

As far as I know is that "Sleep mode" is the "Standby Mode". You could also force that by using:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true
```

and wake it up

```
adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> false
adb shell am get-inactive <packageName>
```

Also to be noted when the device is being charged the system goes out of the idle mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this is DOZE mode. What I mean is sleep, which is supposed to start when the screen turns off. Wake locks are independent from doze, because doze ignores wake locks (as stated in the description)

Comment: @FlorianWalther Sleep mode does not start immediately after turning the screen off. One second

Comment: @FlorianWalther I am sure "Sleep mode" and "Standby Mode" are synonyms. You could force the Standby Mode via adb shell.

Comment: I tested standby mode thoroughly (screen off, power unplugged, discharging, 0 wake locks), but every functionality I tested kept working as if the device was active.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Did you try the adb shell commands? That's the only way to ensure that you went into the desired mode.

Comment: Yes I tested them

Comment: @FlorianWalther Then I can not add anything more. Could be manufacturer specific.

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "What I mean is sleep, which is supposed to start when the screen turns off" -- not necessarily. "I've also checked via adb if another application is holding a wake lock, but the wake lock count is 0" -- then, by definition, your device is connected via `adb` and therefore might not enter sleep mode.

Comment: But I can send it to sleep via adb commands. At the very least I know that I can put the device into doze (does this also imply sleep?), because I can see jobs getting deferred. However, if I do the same while a service is running, the service is not affected at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare So would you say that services generally need a wake lock if they should when the app is not active?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: If by "not active" you mean "without having a foreground activity", then you will need to acquire a wakelock to ensure that the CPU stays powered on. Doze mode/app standby allow Android to ignore that wakelock, which is why they have caused such consternation. And the objective should be to acquire the wakelock for as little time as possible with as much user control as is practical, as keeping the CPU powered on will drain the battery.

Comment: Ok and is the same the case for foreground services? Should they keep a wake lock?

Comment: And maybe you can take a look at this question (I assume that you enjoy talking about services, since you answer so many of them):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322723/intentservice-acquiring-wakelock-in-oncreate-vs-onhandleintent

Comment: I have used above commands to enter doze and appStandBy modes. But now I can not revert it. Everytime the screen goes off, the phone enters the doze mode instantly. Can you help me? I was planning on factory reset it